# Slow down Console speed

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this program, which prints a sine wave but it's too fast, how can I slow down the console's line printing speed?

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim x As Double = 0
        Do
            Console.Write(times(" ", Math.Sin(x) * 10 + 30))
            Console.WriteLine("@")
            x += 0.1
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Function times(ByVal ch As Char, ByVal t As Integer) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        For i = 0 To t
            result += ch
        Next

        Return result
    End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1))`.
(Although you may want `FromSeconds` instead)

Answer (score 3):

I usually prefer: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(miliseconds)`, easier syntax in my own opinion of course. ;-)